# Get Plans Info in Android Application

Tags: java, android, mobile, android-activity

I'm newbie to android application development, and I'm working on an app that requires access to the tariff plans and the net plans active on the SIM card. How can this be done?
Can anybody give a brief startup idea?

Comment: I doubt this is possible with simple API until and unless provider of the SIM provides that information, it would be privacy invasion it would have been so simple

Comment: So, is there any way that, if some there is a msg on our sim, then instead of going in inbox(as it usually does) it is redirected to our app?

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way.
You must send text or call the customer service to get your plan details.